# Get multiple id's

Tags: xml, xquery

I have this xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<employees> 
  <empinfo>
    <employee id="001"/>
    <name>Johny</name>
  </empinfo>
  <empinfo>
    <employee id="002"/>
    <name>Williams</name>
  </empinfo>
  <empinfo>
    <employee id="003"/> 
    <name>Sameer</name>
  </empinfo>
</employees>
```

How will I able to get multiple `id`s?

I have tried this much for getting a single `id`:

```
for $x in doc("emp.xml")/employees
where $x/name = Johny
return $x/@id
```

Comment: Well... You only have one employee with `name = Johny`. Did you try changing the query?

Answer (score 1):

Why don't use XPath?

To get single id (by name):

```
employees/empinfo[@name='Johny']/id
```

To get all:

```
employees/empinfo/id
```

Comment: Transformation is failed..it is showing message of : local variable encountered whose binding has been deleted.

Comment: The OP isn't using XPath but XQuery. I don't think there is an XSLT.

Comment: @Kobi: I thought about XSLT because he quoted an error he got "Transformation is failed.."

Comment: @ABCD: Which implementation are you using?  Without more information this sounds like a bug.